# Label or define a set of statements in C++

Tags: c++, c, label, c-preprocessor

I have been trying to write a program which is somewhat long:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespaces std;
void main()
{
    //first part of program
    ...  //initializing and displaying progress
    ...
    //second part of program
    ... //processing
    ...
    //last part of program
    ... //printing results
    ...
}
```

I don't want to define functions, or use OOP, but still want to be able to organize the code into chunks:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespaces std;
void main()
{
    label 1 ;
    label 2 ;
    label 3 ;
}

label 1 :
{    //first part of program
     ...  //initializing and displaying progress
     ...
}

label 2 :
{    //second part of program
     ...  //processing
     ...
}
label 3 :
{    //last part of program
     ...  //printing results
     ...
}
```

Is this possible in C++?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use functions instead of labels, which is common in C language.

Comment: If the performance is the issue, you should mention in your requirements explicitly in the question. IMO, in most of the cases, you won't notice the difference between using function vs code written only within main() block. Moreover, it is common to sacrifice a little bit from performance in order to make your code more manageable with functions or OOP-style.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning about performance, but i already knew the performance time difference between the two-three approaches.
here is sample code and the time difference is significant. . . 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8_P3mo_Mn5RUVYxVVdIbWhnOGs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have function calls in the program you can use `inline` functions:

```
inline void first_part()
{    //first part of program
     ...  //initializing and displaying progress
     ...
}

void main()
{
    first_part();
    ...
}
```

And use build with optimizations turned on.